# wrapping some content except the first element

Tags: jquery

I would like to wrap all elements of a container except the first one:

```
<div class="anyclass">
    <p>First</p>
    <p>Second</p>
    <ul><li>List</li></ul>
    <p>Third</p>
</div>
```

This should become

```
<div class="anyclass">
    <p>First</p>
    <div class="wrapit">
        <p>Second</p>
        <ul><li>List</li></ul>
        <p>Third</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work.

```
$( ".anyclass p, anyclass ul" ).wrapAll( "<div class='wrapit' />");
```

Also it wraps ALL elements. But I need the exception of the first element.

**Update:** And how can I do it the other way round? That means, just unwrapping the .wrapit-container.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('.anyclass').children('p,ul').not(':first-child').wrapAll('<div class="wrapit" />');
```

should do the trick

unwrapping can be done by the [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) function:

```
$('.anyclass').children('.wrapit').children().unwrap();
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do that generally? I mean: Not only p- and ul-elements.

Comment: yeah of course, 'p,ul' is just a selector for `.children()`. If you just do `$('.anyclass').children(':not(:first-child)').wrapAll(...)` that would do the same

Comment: Just a last question (see updated post). How do I unwrap the new one?